# How do I output ASCII Art to console?

Tags: powershell, console, ascii

I would like to spice up my scripts with some ASCII art to be displayed on completion of a process.

I have 2 thoughts on how to output ASCII art to console.  Hopefully someone who knows more than I do can direct us to what the command is and what method is 'Better'.

1. Output a multi-line `Write-Host`? I tried to do this earlier and it didnt work. It threw a bunch of errors.  Maybe I wasnt doing the 'multi-line' version (if a multi-line) version exists.
2. Save the ASCII art to a .txt file, then in my script somehow grab and read the contents of that .txt file and then write the contents to the console in the specified area.

Which way is better? How can I implement this?

Comment: Where is your input coming from or are you putting in inline? Here-String is the best approach for inline.

Comment: @Matt: I've found rarely a need for here-strings in PowerShell, actually, since normal strings do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: the input is the ASCII art.  The input is either embedded internally in the script OR it is in an external .txt file that would need to be retrieved and read.

Comment: @Joey  I use them more when I need to do formatting or regex matches. Still an easy way so save them in a script but yes... not required.

Comment: @joey here-stings handle quotes better. Ascii art could likely have quotes in it.

Comment: @Matt I thought the Get-Content -Raw was the best method.  Thanks for the help!! I got it working :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use a newline delimited string, here-string or `Get-Content -Raw` if you have a source file. Both will give you a single multiline string without fuss. One thing the here-string is good for is not having to worry about the quotes you use (which could be a distinct possibility with ASCII art). An example using a here-string would be the following:

```
$text = @"
 "ROFL:ROFL:ROFL:ROFL"
         _^___
 L    __/   [] \    
LOL===__        \ 
 L      \________]
         I   I
        --------/
"@
```

Or if you choose to go the source file approach:

```
$text = Get-Content -Raw $path
```

Or if you only have PowerShell 2.0 `$text = Get-Content $path | Out-String`

Either way you can follow up with `Write-Host` or whatever you want after that.

---

Getting funky with colours would require some special logic that, as far as I know, does not currently exist. Making a colourized output randomizer is simple enough. To get a basic idea I present `Get-Funky`

```
function Get-Funky{
    param([string]$Text)

    # Use a random colour for each character
    $Text.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object{
        switch -Regex ($_){
            # Ignore new line characters
            "`r"{
                break
            }
            # Start a new line
            "`n"{
                Write-Host " ";break
            }
            # Use random colours for displaying this non-space character
            "[^ ]"{
                # Splat the colours to write-host
                $writeHostOptions = @{
                    ForegroundColor = ([system.enum]::GetValues([system.consolecolor])) | get-random
                    # BackgroundColor = ([system.enum]::GetValues([system.consolecolor])) | get-random
                    NoNewLine = $true
                }
                Write-Host $_ @writeHostOptions
                break
            }
            " "{Write-Host " " -NoNewline}

        } 
    }
}
```

That will take a newline delimited string and use random host colours for displaying the output. We use splatting with `$writeHostOptions` so you could easily control the colours. You could even have parameters that force one of the colours or disabled colourizing of one etc. Here is some sample output:

```
$art = " .:::.   .:::.`n:::::::.:::::::`n:::::::::::::::
':::::::::::::'`n  ':::::::::'`n    ':::::'`n      ':'"
Get-Funky $art
```

[image: Funky heart]

Heart ascii art found at [asciiworld.com](http://www.asciiworld.com/-Hearts-.html)

Answer (score 10):

It's a piece of my PowerShell `$PROFILE`:

```
# Personalize the console
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Windows Powershell " + $Host.Version;

# Draw welcome screen
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                       _oo0oo_"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                      o8888888o"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                      88`" . `"88"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                      (| -_- |)"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                      0\  =  /0"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                    ___/`----'\___"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                  .' \\|     |// '."
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                 / \\|||  :  |||// \"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                / _||||| -:- |||||- \"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "               |   | \\\  -  /// |   |"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "               | \_|  ''\---/''  |_/ |"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "               \  .-\__  '-'  ___/-. /"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "             ___'. .'  /--.--\  `. .'___"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "          .`"`" '<  `.___\_<|>_/___.' >' `"`"."
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "         | | :  `- \`.;`\ _ /`;.`/ - ` : | |"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "         \  \ `_.   \_ __\ /__ _/   .-` /  /"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "     =====`-.____`.___ \_____/___.-`___.-'====="
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "                       `=---='"


# Create frequent commands
New-Alias -Name vsc -Value "D:\Program Files\VSCode\Code.exe";
$HOSTS = "$env:SystemRoot\system32\drivers\etc\hosts";
$Desktop = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop"
$Documents = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents"
$TimestampServer = "http://timestamp.digicert.com"
Set-Location D:\Scripts;
```

Just a reference.

Comment: I would totally convert that to a single multi line string. That way you would only have to change the colour once!

Comment: Write the pattern to `@'blabla'@` is much easier to read, I just copied it from Internet. :)

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell can do multi-line strings (with all kinds of strings; this isn't limited to here-strings), so the following should work, actually:

```
Write-Host 'first line
second line
third line'
```

Of course, if you're not in a function and don't care about any return values, you can just omit `Write-Host` completely. If you're reading from an external file, then in the same vein, `Get-Content` would just work:

```
Get-Content ascii.txt
```

if you really need Write-Host, then just use

```
Get-Content | % { Write-Host $_ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example that does multi-line using Write-Host

```
Write-Host "  ***   ** ** ** ** * ********
>>               **** ******* ********* *                     
>>                **   *****   ********  *                    
>>                *     ***     ******    *                   
>>                       *       ****     *                   
>>                                **                         
>>                                 *                          
>> "
```

**UPDATED**: Removed the backslashes as they are not needed in PowerShell

Comment: Uhm, what purpose would the backslashes serve there?

Comment: To continue the line on the next line.. I guess you can also do without it

Comment: Backslashes aren't escape characters in PowerShell strings, and escaping isn't even required here.

Answer (score 2):

Here-strings are also perfectly good arguments to `Write-Host`:

```
$multiplelines = @"
Multi-lines?!

Well ... Why
not?

"@

Write-Host $multiplelines
```